# Why is vim indenting my Perl code incorrectly?

Tags: perl, vim, indentation, vim-perl

I have a subroutine in Perl that should be indented like this:

```
sub GetFiles 
{
    my $pwd = shift;
    my @input = @_;
    my @returned;

    my @DirectoryContent = &GetContentInformation(@input);

    foreach (@DirectoryContent) 
    {
        my %current = %{$_};

        if ($current{'info'} =~ /<DIR>/) 
        {
            my $RecurseDir = &GetRecurseDir($pwd, \%current);
            push(@returned, &GetFiles($RecurseDir, 
                    &GetDirectoryContents($RecurseDir)));
        }
        else 
        { 
            # clean up the data
            my $size = $current{'info'};
            # filesize will be in number of bytes
            # remove file separators
            #$size =~ s/,//g; 
            my $extension = &GetFileExtension($current{'name'});
            delete($current{'info'});
            $current{'size'} = $size;
            $current{'extension'} = $extension;
            # push(@returned, \%current);
        }
     }
     @returned;
}
```

But when I press `=%` (yes, `cindent` is on) with the cursor on the starting bracket of the subroutine block, it indents it like this:

```
sub GetFiles 
{   
    my $pwd = shift;
    my @input = @_;
    my @returned;

    my @DirectoryContent = &GetContentInformation(@input);

    foreach (@DirectoryContent) 
    {
        my %current = %{$_};

        if ($current{'info'} =~ /<DIR>/) 
        {
            my $RecurseDir = &GetRecurseDir($pwd, \%current);
        push(@returned, &GetFiles($RecurseDir, &GetDirectoryContents($RecurseDir)));
    }
    else 
    { 
        # clean up the data
        my $size = $current{'info'};
        # filesize will be in number of bytes
        # remove file separators
        #$size =~ s/,//g; 
        my $extension = &GetFileExtension($current{'name'});
        delete($current{'info'});
        $current{'size'} = $size;
        $current{'extension'} = $extension;
        # push(@returned, \%current);
    }
}
@returned;
}
```

Why does it do that? How can I fix it?

EDIT: It should be noted that I am using gvim 7.3 on Windows.

Comment: I don't know perl, but the problem is the `\%current`, removing the `\\` seems to let vim indent this properly.  Whether or not that is something valid in perl is another question.

Comment: I don't like to pollute answers, so I would like to ask first: do you know about perltidy?

Comment: @RandyMorris : it's valid perl, but removing the operator did let vim do it's work. perhaps there is a slight bug in the indentation file, which I may be able to fix :) thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this is magical thinking, but … I used to have:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

in my `_vimrc` (on Windows XP, self-compiled `gvim`, various versions), and I would get all sorts of interesting indentation problems in Perl, LaTeX, and HTML files.

Now, I have

```
filetype indent on 
filetype plugin on
```

and everything seems to be hunk-dory. YMMV.

Also, I highly recommend [Andy Lester's vim-perl](https://github.com/petdance/vim-perl).

Comment: In fact, (and I didn't know this,) Andy Lester's vim-perl is the perl indentation file shipped with gvim 7.3. The revision is as of June 3, 2009 though, and there are TODO's at the top. I will check to see if he has updated his file.

Comment: Updating Andy Lester's perl files worked. Thanks for the tip, and to everyone helping me track down the error :).

Answer (score 3):

`cindent` is specific to the `c` language and is broken when used with a lot of other languages. What you probably want to use is `filetype plugin indent on`. You can add that to your `.vimrc` and vim will figure out the correct syntax/indentation for most languages out of the box. You can also add syntax/indentation guides fairly easily if vim doesn't already have them.

Comment: I turn my cindent off, and put in `filetype plugin indent on`, but it still gives similar results. Insightful answer, though :)

Comment: I tested this out and the issue still remains. My apologies for the red herring.

Answer (score 2):

My system indents your code correctly using **`filetype indent on`** (versus `filetype`**`plugin`**`indent on`). [Vim 7.2]

Comment: this enforces my 'bug in the file' theory (see above comment).

Comment: trying your code on vim 7.3, it doesn't work properly. Thanks for specifying the version, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked this issue down to a quirk in the vim regular expression matcher, in the perl.vim indent file there are several places where the regular expression includes an attempt to escape a [ in a collection with \[....

```
 **let bracepos = match(line, '[(){}\[\]]', bracepos + 1)**
```

but for whatever reason the \[ matches any \ or [ in the line not just [
so to fix the vim indent file unescape the left brackets in all match statements, ie...

```
 let bracepos = match(line, '[(){}[\]]', bracepos + 1)
```