# Can't use vim-perl unless I stop use "filetype indent on"

Tags: vim, vim-perl

I find the `vim-perl` [plugin here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905836/why-is-vim-indenting-my-perl-code-incorrectly), but I can't enable it with:

`filetype plugin indent on` (I changed the order of "plugin" and "indent" after seeing that link)

I can't disable plugin support, so I tried an alternative way,

```
if &filetype == 'perl'
    filetype plugin on
else
    filetype plugin indent on
endif
```

But that doesn't work either! When I do `filetype` command in VIM, I see `plugin, autodetection, indent` are all ON

Any thoughts?

Comment: How to "can't enable" and "doesn't work" actually manifest themselves?! What is missing / wrong?

Comment: @IngoKarkat “Doesn’t work” means that without `filetype on` filetype is not detected and thus `&filetype` is not equal to `perl` and `:if` condition is always false. “Can’t enable” is much more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> But that doesn't work either! When I do filetype command in VIM, I see plugin, autodetection, indent are all ON

Of course, it would not. `:filetype` also enables filetype detection, thus there is no way you can automatically have `&filetype` equal to `perl` until you have run `:filetype on`.

You can try something like

```
function s:DisablePerlIndent()
    augroup DisablePerlIndent
        if &ft is# 'perl'
            autocmd! BufEnter <buffer> filetype indent off
        else
            autocmd! BufEnter <buffer>
        endif
    augroup END
endfunction
augorup DisablePerlIndent
    autocmd! FileType * call s:DisablePerlIndent()
augroup END
```

, but I doubt this will actually work. It would be much better if you follow @IngoKarkat advice and say what does “can’t enable” mean.